# FIle hole - how is it represented?

Tags: linux, filesystems

`The linux programming interface` says, file hole don't take up disk space in general, I did google but didn't found answer to following question:

If it don't take up space, then how the file system record the byte count of file hole? Does it store an integer somewhere?

---

@Update

I read the book a little more, and got "Section 14.4 describes how holes are represented in a file", I will read that.

Comment: Another key phrase that may be useful for your searches is that a file with holes in is often called a "sparse" file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exact answer depends on your filesystem - but in short, your data is stored in blocks.  Your filesystem's metadata contains pointers to those blocks.  It's OK if those blocks aren't consecutive - if your pointers are to block 3,4,5,6 it's no different than if they point to 3,28,110,45.  It's only the number of blocks that determines how much space is taken up.